# AsyncStorage not working on android, OK in iOS

Tags: android, ios, asyncstorage

On iOS, all works well. I only have a couple of items to add and they are all text strings, but even so I use JSON.stringify. This is on my settings page:

In render I have a switch:

```
  <Switch
        onValueChange = {(languageObject, switchID) => this.toggleLang("ENG", "switchENG")}
        value = {this.state.switchENG}/>
```

which runs this function:

```
 toggleLang = (language, switchID) => {
  const myStates = ["switchENG", "switchFRC", "switchSPN"];
  for(let i = 0; i < myStates.length; i++) {
    if(myStates[i] === switchID) {
      this.setState({[myStates[i]]: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({[myStates[i]]: false});
    }
  };
  this.storeData("language", language);
  }
```

which runs this function:

```
  storeData = async (key, value) => {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
catch(error) {
  console.log("You got this error: " + error);
}
```

}

Then in my main page/screen, I have:

```
 componentDidMount() {  // Listen for when the screen is focused
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
  this.getData();
});
```

}

Which runs this function:

```
  getData = async () => {
   try { // get the language (ENG/FRC/SPN etc) 
     await AsyncStorage.getItem("language").then((value) =>{
       this.setState({selLang: value});
     });
   }
   catch(error) {
     alert("You got this error: " + error);
   }
   }
```

I have my screen temporarily set to render without using AsyncStorage, just for testing purposes, with a function tied to the switch which, when toggled, calls the function to get a language item and change the label's text item to the new language.

As I said, everything works fine on iOS, I can toggle between languages and it's all kept when I reload the app.

I am using expo. In terminal I get: 
      react-native --v
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native: 0.59.8

When I toggle the switch in Android I get:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating "lang.a10")
```

Which seems to indicate that it has not received anything from AsyncStorage.

I really want my app to run when offline so a server store is not what I want. AsyncStorage is perfect. Except it won't work on Android.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not use JSON.stringify if you only want to save string. if you want to save object like this then you can use JSON.stringify**

```
let value = {
  age: 31,
  traits: {eyes: 'blue', shoe_size: 10},
};
await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
```

**Please change this**

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
```

**to**

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(key,value);
```

**so when you receive it will give you string not an object in these lines**

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem("language").then((value) =>{
       this.setState({selLang: value});
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had it as you said, but changed it "just in case".

But the error was there on Android either way.

I figured it out though. It was my fault, not Android/AsyncStorage. I was calling a function twice, using a different key. So in the componentDidMount I was calling two functions, getData(key1) then right after getData(key2).

For some  some reason, when the second function fired, which happened to be using the language key, it was returning "FRC" including the quote marks, and not just FRC. So my screen was looking for a switch called switch"FRC" instead of switchFRC.

I was getting the correct result for my first function, but not the second. Weird. To get things woking again, I just made a second function, getDataB(key2) and now it's all working fine. Still weird though that it worked on iOS.

Thanks for your help though, it got me writing heaps of console.logs and eventually tracked it down.

Answer (score 1):

After adjusting a few things I am still having the issue of IOS working fine but on Android I am getting "null" back from AsyncStorage.

My current function is:

```
 getData = async () => {
     try {
       const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("language");
       console.log("the value is: " + value);
       if (value !== null) {
        const myLang = Languages[value];
        console.log("It worked: " + value);
       }
      } catch (error) {
       alert("You got this error from Plates.js: " + error);
     }
   };
```

In the Terminal I get:

```
 Running application on iPhone Xs.
 the value is: SWE
 It worked: SWE

 Running application on Android SDK built for x86.
 the value is: null
```

To me, that means that Android is skipping the entire AsyncStorage function.

I have tried making new projects and it seems to work OK so something is amiss with my code. It's a big project so wondering if there is a Debugging test I can try to see what's happening in the background.